# Python Multiprocessing PyInstaller- Weird issue when trying to start processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

Hi I'm trying to run a simple multiprocessing using Python and Multiprocessing.

My Main Process is a GUI made in PyQt5. Upon a button click, it calls the function `runSesisons()` which will trigger `p.start()`.

Here's my simple code for starting the process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, freeze_support

def session(x):
    print(x)

def runSessions():
    p = Process(target=session, args=("Hello",))
    freeze_support()
    p.start()
```

When everything is still a .py file, everything works normally.

However, after I pack it into an .exe with pyinstaller using this command "pyinstaller --onefile main.py", I notice that when I click the same button to trigger `runSessions()`, it duplicates the PyQt5 program process.

Here's a Gif to show what I mean.

In this Gif, I first run the program using Visual Studio Code to show it works. Then I run the program after it's packed with pyinstaller to show its weird behaviour.

[image]

I'm running Python 3.7 and I hope you guys are able to help me. Thanks!
I've never encountered this as I've always used Multithreading.

**UPDATE 1**

I read somewhere that I need to start the processes under this `if '__name__' == __main__`, But... I can't. I'm trying to start the processes when I click a button

Comment: try to use QThread instead of any other thread library

Comment: @stilManiac I need to create multiple Processes. Not threads.

Comment: QProcess. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qprocess.html

Comment: @stilManiac could you leave an answer with a little bit of code example? That would help a lot. i'm unable to find any solid simple tutorial on qprocess.

Comment: hm, you are not able to create a new process without creating a new program instance. If you run external process, that will work correctly, but here you're trying to run a program's function in a new process.This is how processes work. Use threads instead.